# Styled components component selector not working on mouse hover

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to build that behavior illustrated by the following GIF on mouse hover.

[image]

The user can make the **red** selection by using the **Arrow keys**, but on mouse hover, I want to hide the **red** selection and show only the mouse hover **green** selection.

[Code Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5k301w7rr)

It is working, so far.

But somehow it breaks when I try to use the component selector: `${S.UserLi}`, which is the name of my styled component for each `li`. It only works when I select general `li` items, like you can see in the following code (Sandbox link above).

**QUESTION**

How can I make it work using my component selector `${S.UserLi}` ?

```
S.MentionDiv = styled.div`
  max-width: 200px;
  height : auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ul {
    margin: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    li { background-color: inherit; } /* THIS WORKS */
    /* ${S.UserLi} { background-color: inherit; } */ /*THIS DOESN'T*/
  }
`;

S.UserLi = styled.li`
  background-color: ${props => props.selected ? 'red' : 'inherit'};
  &&:hover { /* Added two && to make it higher priority over hover on MentionDiv */
    background-color:lightgreen;
    user-select: none;
  }
`;
```

This is the main component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <S.MentionDiv>
      <S.UserLi>
        User 1
      </S.UserLi>
      <S.UserLi
        selected={true}
      >
        User 2
      </S.UserLi>
      <S.UserLi>
        User 3
      </S.UserLi>
    </S.MentionDiv>
  );
}
```

Comment: quick solution to make the *specificity* work: define `S.UserLi` above the `S.MentionDiv` and give `!important` to `background-color: lightgreen`... https://codesandbox.io/s/7zz35wl4r0

Comment: @kukkuz It worked! Thanks! Why does the order of declaration matter? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not very sure.either, but I can see `background-color: inherit` getting applied on the `S.MentionDiv` too when I inspect element :|

Comment: it makes sense if you think that this is javascript & not css. Accessing `${S.Li}` before its definition will return `undefined`, since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @DerekNguyen you are right! Declarations are hoisted, but initializations are not. Just filled that gap in my knowledge. Thanks!